# draw with finger with custom paint in flutter

Tags: flutter

I made a painting page, everything is ok and I save the data on the server and display it on another device, but when I display the white page with the painting on it, it is small and the painting comes out. How can I make this painting responsive with custompaint size?
i use it like this:

```
   GestureDetector(
                        onPanUpdate: (details) async {
                          setState(() {
                            _points.add(DrawingPoint(
                                points: details.globalPosition,
                                color: _color,
                                strokeWidth: strokewidth));
                          });
                        },
                        onPanEnd: (details) => _points.add(null),
                        child: CustomPaint(
                          painter: DrawingPainter(
                            _points,
                          ),
                          size: Size.infinite,
                        ),
                      ),
```

and my custom paint :

```
class DrawingPainter extends CustomPainter {
  DrawingPainter(
    this.points,
  );

  final List<DrawingPoint?> points;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
      if (points[i] != null && points[i + 1] != null) {
        canvas.drawLine(
            points[i]!.points,
            points[i + 1]!.points,
            Paint()
              ..color = points[i]!.color
              ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
              ..strokeWidth = points[i]!.strokeWidth);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(DrawingPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

[for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qOTd.png)